# How did the blind man make his way to the pool of Siloam? The Word says he returned sighted after washing in the pool.

Tags: john

John 9 has the blind man ‘going to wash in the pool of Siloam.’ How did get get there? The Word says he returned sighted only after washing in the pool.

Comment: As with many accounts in the scriptures, every detail is not always given. Logic would dictate, 1. either the man was close to the pool and could easily reach it, 2. He was skillful in navigating his locale as many blind people are today or 3. he had someone lead him to the pool.

Comment: What was the purpose of asking?

Comment: @Kris I was reading this familiar passage & asked myself the question & wondered if anyone had some insight on it.

Comment: Having been born blind and given that he was well known in the town he likley had become quite familiar with his surroundings. He could no doubt navigate his normal daily journey on his own. His friends and family were available to assist him when needed.

Comment: Nathaniel it's a wonderful question. +1

Comment: I want to answer the question from a prophetic standpoint. The waters of Siloam were rejected by Israel according to Isaiah 8.  Hence God said he would bring the waters of the River (King of Assyria) to overflow the land and reach up to the neck.

Comment: Siloam's waters run outside the city of David and these waters represent the Davidic dynasty that was rejected by the ten tribes of Israel. This resulted in the subjugation of Israel's ten tribes by the Assyrian.

Comment: Israel's rejection of Siloam is also a rejection of the "sent"; the prophets and ultimately the Messiah. Hence when Jesus told him to wash at Siloam, there were deeper implications behind that command. I'll collect my comments into an answer but I'm scared of the trolls who down vote anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

John 9:1 As he went along, he saw a man blind from birth. 2His disciples asked him, “Rabbi, who sinned, this man or his parents, that he was born blind?”

How did this blind man get to this spot in the first place?

Acts 3:2 may provide a clue:

> And a man who was lame from birth was being carried to the temple gate called Beautiful, where **he was put every day** to beg from those entering the temple courts.

How did the blind man make his way to the pool of Siloam?

Perhaps his friends, perhaps some strangers helped him along.

Answer (score 0):

The only record for a blind person using help in the first century was evidence of a seeing eye dog.

> But when exactly man’s best friend became an aide to people with disabilities and other challenges remains a mystery. The earliest evidence of such partnerships—a fresco in which a blind man is led by his dog, discovered amid the ruins of the ancient Roman city Herculaneum—dates back to the first century A.D. European wood carvings and Chinese scroll paintings from the Middle Ages depict similar scenes. -- https://www.history.com/news/assistance-dogs-learning-new-tricks-for-centuries

There is no evidence that the blind man in John 9 had a seeing eye dog, but it does show things the blind used to walk did exist in the first century.  Using white canes to identify blind are only a few centuries old, but feeling with canes, sticks, and even feet may well have been in use in the first century.